# . (dot) shows up as path separator

Tags: files

I'm hunting a really strange bug:

```
arian@orel:~$ ls ._cache.<tab><tab>
Display all 205 possibilities? (y or n)
._cache.apt-file/
._cache.chromium/
._cache.chromium.Default/
._cache.chromium.Default.Cache/
._cache.chromium.Default.Media Cache/
._cache.dconf/
._cache.evolution.mail/
._cache.evolution.mail.1370283652_17412_21@orel/
._cache.evolution.mail.1370283652_17412_21@orel.folders/
._cache.evolution.mail.1370283652_17412_21@orel.folders.Archives/
._cache.evolution.mail.1370283652_17412_21@orel.folders.Archives.subfolders/
...
```

it's like the dot acts as a path separator, except tab completition does not treat it as a path separator and displays the directory recursively. I've seen this behaviour only in this directory. Neither in parent nor child directories and it's not on a separate filesystem. This also shows when accessed from installation media, so seems not to be my operating system. Also shows when accessing via sshfs. `ls` and `find` only show normal paths, but `du` does also show these period-stuff.

I did fsck on the FS

I noticed a file named

```
playlist.pls\?action\=playlist\&type\=pls\&sid\=545\&stream_id\=1711
```

in the directory. on moving this somewhere else, the behaviour vanished. So it seems there is some bug in handling these characters, right? Well, I can chdir where I moved the file, create some files and directories and this behaviour did not show up. 
I `touch`ed some files with `\&`,`\?` and `\=` and combinations in their names, with normal behaviour.
I moved the `playlist.pls\?action\=playlist\&type\=pls\&sid\=545\&stream_id\=1711` file back and no abnormal behaviour showed up.

I am not really sure on what to do here. There is some bug for sure, at least fsck should detect possible error on disk if all code worked correctly, right? I have also no idea what code is faulty.

I could not reproduce this bug once I moved said file.

Comment: bash/zsh/ksh/csh/etc?

Comment: It's not a path separator. It's just directories named like that (with dots in their names). It's typical of some maildir structures like courier imap server.

Comment: How do you know the directories aren't really called that?

Comment: I'm more  curious about what behavior disappeared...?

Comment: Try installing/running the `tree` command - this should show how exactly how everything is arranged.

Answer (score 1):

There are files and folders starting with "._cache." but you don't normally see them with the `ls` command as they are hidden files. All files starting with `.` are considered hidden files in Linux. to have ls display them, use the `-a` option.

```
# ls
a-not-hidden-file
another-not-hidden-file
a-not-hidden-folder/
# ls -a
.hidden-file
.another-hidden-file
.a-hidden-folder/
a-not-hidden-file
another-not-hidden-file
a-not-hidden-folder/
```